# Random crashes with Eclipse window builder plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I have been learning JFrame recently and I installed Eclipse window builder plugin in my eclipse 2019-09. The plugin installed without any error but after say working on 5 mins on the designer then eclipse crashes... How to fix this?

Here is the error log: https://sourceb.in/d4c150060b

Comment: Crashes like this are caused by bugs in the JVM or the native code used by Eclipse/SWT. So make sure you are using the latest update for your releases of Java and Eclipse. The dump says you have Java 8 update 45 - update 231 is the latest for that.

Comment: ok then I am updating Java

Comment: @greg-449 same error

Comment: Which WindowBuilder version? Do you have installed other plug-ins in addition to the WindowBuilder?

Comment: @howlger, latest

Comment: @howlger and I have lombok, cordota installed in addition to WindowBuilder

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with [Eclipse 2019-12 RC1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-12/rc1) without additional plug-ins?